# How to reverse bitwise AND (&) in C?

Tags: c, reverse, bitwise-operators

How to reverse bitwise AND (&) in C?

For example I have an operation in C like this:

```
((unsigned int)ptr & 0xff000000))
```

The result is `0xbf000000`. What I need at this moment is how to reverse the above, i.e. determine `ptr` by using the result from the operation and of course `0xff000000`.

Is there any simple way to implement this in C?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bitwise `&` can't be reversed:

```
0 & 1 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 21):

You can't do that because you have thrown away information (i.e. bits) - you can't get information back from nowhere.

Note that both `AND` (`&`) and `OR` (`|`) are destructive. The only Boolean operations that are reversible are `XOR` (`^`) and NOT (`~`).

Answer (score 5):

Impossible. Bitwise & of 0xff000000 is a lossy operation. You lose the lower 24-bits permanently.

Answer (score 4):

You can only reverse XOR, as it's non-destructive.

Both OR and AND are destructive.