# Reverse bitwise AND operation

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reverse bitwise AND (&) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566225/how-to-reverse-bitwise-and-in-c)

If I am using bitwise AND

```
7758194 & 255 = 114
```

how could I get back `7758194`, given the result `114`?

Comment: use XOR instead.............?

Comment: That's like asking "given half a phone number, how can I get the other half?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The & operator, bitwise or not, is simply not reversible.

```
0 & 1 => 0
0 & 0 => 0
1 & 0 => 0
```

So you can't.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you expose the real problem in another question. Maybe you need XOR as suggested by Mitch Wheat.