# How to reverse a bitwise OR operation?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Here's what I've done:

```
93 | 199
```

which returns

```
223
```

I understand that this is because `0b1011101 | 0b11000111` is `0b11011111`

However, suppose I want to do the reverse operation. How do I get `0b1011101` from a bitwise operation between `0b11000111` and `0b11011111`?

Comment: You could generate all possible answers, there may be exponentially many of them though (3 to the power of the number of 1's)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't get an unambiguous answer in the general case. If `C=A|B`, then wherever you have a 1 in C and a 1 in B, the corresponding bit of A *could have been either* 0 or 1.

In your example, 93|199=223, but 92|199 is also 223. So, given 223 and 199 there's no single answer (in fact, in this example there are 32 possible answers).

Answer (score 6):

**Keep Bit Frequency Table**

Although there is no deterministic way to get other operand back using only bit-wise operation, this may help.

You can keep a table to store the bit frequency. Then the number you want to remove from the OR result, decrease frequency of bits where the bit is 'set'(1) for this number. The places where the frequency is greater than zero, 'set' those bits in the answer.

**Example:**

```
A   :   0101  
B   :   1110  

------------  
OR :    1111 

[frequency]
+-+-+-+-+  
|1|2|1|1|  
+-+-+-+-+

Now, you have the OR and B, you want to get A back. 
Decrease the frequency table in indices where B has set bits.

[frequency-updated]
+-+-+-+-+  
|0|1|0|1|  
+-+-+-+-+
As you can see, the non-zero indices indicates where the A's bits were set.
```

This process can be extended to set of N numbers, where you have bit-wise OR of N numbers and you want to know what the OR would be 'without' some number X from the set.

**Complexity**

*Time Complexity:* For a number N, time complexity for a single operation is *log(N)*, since there are *log(N)* number of bits to iterate.

*Space Complexity:* For M amount of numbers with size N, space complexity is *Mlog(N)*, since there are *log(N)* bits to store for all *M* numbers.

Thanks @hussein-hammoud for mentioning the complexity.

Comment: perfect answer. was looking for it :). Don't forget to mention the complexity which is log(size_of_n)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566225/how-to-reverse-bitwise-and-in-c), both **OR and AND are destructive** operations. Reversing OR operation is a lossy operation and as mentioned by 'jez' can have more than one answer. *So, it is not possible*

Only reverse operation possible is for **XOR as it is non-destructive**.

Comment: what are the benefits of xor being non destructive?