# Given an array of positive integers, find bitwise AND of a subarray, among all subarrays, which is closest to a given positive integer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

Given an array of positive integers, find bitwise AND of a subarray, among all subarrays, which is closest to a given positive integer, 'P'.

The solution can obviously be found in O(n^2), but can we do better?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657935/listing-bitwise-ands-of-all-subarrays-where-i-j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing bitwise ands of all subarrays where i <= j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657935/listing-bitwise-ands-of-all-subarrays-where-i-j)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to cite the original source of the problem?